# I am trying to run this code that asks user to enter a sentence, the display the number of vowels and consonants in the sentence

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, syntax-error

I am getting syntax errors when trying to run or sometimes it runs but does not execute the way I am intending it to.

I have been playing around with the formatting but still no solution.

```
def checkVowelsConsonants(s):
    vowels=0
    consonants=0
    for ch in s:
#convert character into its ASCII equivalent
        ascii_value=ord(ch)
#if ASCII is between 65 to 90 to 97 to 122 then it's a character
#otherwise a special character
    if((ascii_value>=65 and ascii_value<=90)or(ascii_value>=97 and ascii_value<=122)):
#check for lower case
        if ch=='a' or ch=='e' or ch=='i' or ch=='o' or ch=='u':
            vowels=vowels+1
#check for upper case
    elif ch=='A' or ch=='E' or ch=='I' or ch=='O' or ch=='U':
            vowels=vowels+1
    else:
        consonants=consonants+1
#print the result
        print("The number of vowels is "+str(vowels)+" and consonants is "+str(consonants))

while True:
#print the menu
        print("1. Print the number of vowels and consonats")
        print("2. Exit the program")
#take choioce as input from user
        choice=int(input("Enter choice: "))
#take sentence input from user
        if choice==1:
            sentence=input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence_list=[]
for ch in sentence:
    sentence_list.append(ch)
    checkVowelsConsonants(sentence_list)
#exit the program
if choice==2:
    break
#choice other that 1 and 2
else:
    print("Invalid choice!")
```

Comment: tip: `elif ch=='A' or ch=='E' or ch=='I' or ch=='O' or ch=='U':` can be written as `if ch in "AEIOU":`. `ascii_value>=65 and ascii_value<=90`  can be written as `65 <= ascii_value <= 90` I'd also recommend indenting the comments, since they make your code completely unreadable. Could you correct those things and post the code again?

Comment: The syntax error you're getting is because of `break`? You need to make sure that your indentation is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleaned up your code, checking ascii values with `65 <= ascii_value <= 90`.
As you want to check lowercase and upper case vowels I made this one if condition by checking if `ch in "aeiouAEIOU"` making all other valid characters lowercase or uppercase consonants.

It is also not necessary to convert your user input `sentence` to a list prior to your `checkVowelsConsonants` call, as a string is also iterable.
That is why I removed that `for` loop appending each individual character.
But if that was intended by you, just leave as is.

By following your code I indented it so that your `while` loop only terminates when `choice` is `2`.

```py
def checkVowelsConsonants(s):
    vowels = 0
    consonants = 0
    for ch in s:
        # Convert character into its ASCII equivalent
        ascii_value = ord(ch)
        # If ASCII is between 65 to 90 or 97 to 122 then it's a character
        # otherwise a special character
        if (65 <= ascii_value <=90) or(97 <= ascii_value <= 122):
            # Check for lower case and upper case vowels
            if ch in "aeiouAEIOU":
                vowels = vowels + 1
            else:
                consonants = consonants + 1
    # Print the result
    print("The number of vowels is " + str(vowels) + " and consonants is " + str(consonants))

while True:
    # Print the menu
    print("1. Print the number of vowels and consonats")
    print("2. Exit the program")
    # Take choice as input from user
    choice = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    # Take sentence input from user
    if choice == 1:
        sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
        checkVowelsConsonants(sentence)
    # Exit the program
    elif choice == 2:
        break
    # choice other than 1 or 2
    else:
        print("Invalid choice!")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add:

The program doesn't end even with selection of choice 1. So, here I have rewritten the code and added a `break` after the choice input. I have also used string formatted text to keep things a bit cleaner. Here below:

```
def checkVowelsConsonants(s):
    vowels = 0
    consonants = 0
    for ch in s:
        ascii_value = ord(ch)
        if ((ascii_value >= 65 & ascii_value <= 90) | (ascii_value >= 97 & ascii_value <= 122)):
#check for lower case
            if ch == 'a' or ch == 'e' or ch == 'i' or ch == 'o' or ch == 'u':
                vowels = vowels+1
#check for upper case
            elif ch == 'A' or ch == 'E' or ch == 'I' or ch == 'O' or ch == 'U':
                vowels +=1
            else:
                consonants +=1
#print the result
    print("The number of vowels is {} and consonants is {}".format(vowels,consonants))

    
while True:
#print the menu
    print("Choices:")    
    print("1: Print the number of vowels and consonants")
    print("2: Exit the program\n")
#take choioce as input from user
    choice = int(input("Enter choice: \n"))
#take sentence input from user
    if choice == 1:
        sentence = input("Enter a sentence: \n")
        checkVowelsConsonants(sentence)
        break
#exit the program
    elif choice == 2:
        print('Program exited.')
        break
#choice other that 1 and 2
    else:
        print("Invalid choice!")
```